# React Native openID Connect auth password flow no web browser

Tags: react-native, openid-connect

I have to connect to a server using OpenID, using [IdentityServer4](https://demo.identityserver.io/) using a react native client.

The problem is that I cannot find libraries that implement the client but with password flow, no web login, so the app sends via API all the values, not using a web browser and a callback.

all the libraries I find use the web browser way like [react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth)

Are there any libraries to handle the client for OIDC on react native that work with out a web browser?

Or do I have to roll my own?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LIBRARIES**

Would the nodejs [openid-client](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client) library work for you? If so, here is some [password grant code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.basicloadtest/blob/master/src/oauth/authenticator.ts) from a developer load test of mine.

**MOBILE FLOW**

In OAuth, the app itself should not really see the password. Any particular reason why the AppAuth solution doesn't work for you. Just interested in any blocking issues etc and whether I can help

Comment: Hi thanks for the library and the example!, that worked, now I need to try to make work on the react native environment the library openid-client, do you think I can make the library run for react native with something like https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify ? Thanks

Comment: Not something I've ever used so I can't answer that one. I have always used AppAuth libraries as in my [Blog Posts](https://authguidance.com/2019/09/13/android-code-sample-overview/) and that is the recommended solution. It is harder to implement than the password grant, but more correct in security terms.